How to replace HibernateDaoSupport getSessionFactory() setSessionFactory() in Hibernate 6
After migrate to hibernate 6, the call to HibernateDaoSupport getSessionFactory(), HibernateDaoSupport setSessionFactory() is failed with error

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion     at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.HibernateDaoSupport.createHibernateTemplate(HibernateDaoSupport.java:84)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(HibernateDaoSupport.java:70)
at

Then what class and method to use in Hibernate 6 to replace HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory(), setSessionFactory()?
